# chart js showing different width of bar

Tags: vue.js, charts, chart.js

I am creating simple bar chart using Chartjs in Vue

```
<bar-chart
            :data="[40, 19, 3, 5,]"
            :labels="['0-30 days', '31-60 days', '61-90 days', '90+']"
            :colors="['blue', 'blue', 'blue', 'blue']"
            
            ></bar-chart>
```

and the code for this is

```
 
  createChart(chartData: object) {
  
    const canvas = document.getElementById('bar') as HTMLCanvasElement;
 const myopt = {
      deferred: {
        xOffset: '50%',
        delay: 250,
      },
      plugins: {
        datalabels: {
          align: 'top',
          anchor: 'end',
          color: 'blue',
        },
      },
      legend: {
        display: true,
      },
      title: {
        display: true,
        text: 'Chart.js - Different Bar Colors',
      },
      tooltips: { enabled: true },
      responsive: true,
      hover: { mode: null },
      elements: {
        point: {
          radius: 0,
        },
      },
      scales: {
        xAxes: [{          
          scaleLabel: {
            display: true,
            labelString: '',
          },   
          offset: false,
          color: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)',        
          gridLines: {
            drawOnChartArea: false,
          },
        }],

        yAxes: [{
          id: 'y-axis-0',
          mirror: false,
          stacked: true,
          offset: false,
          callback(label:any, index:any, labels:[]) {
            return `${label}%`;
          },
          ticks: {
            beginAtZero: true,
            min: 0,
          },
          gridLines: {
            display: true,
            color: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)',
            drawOnChartArea: false,
          },
        }],
      },
    };
    const options = {
      type: 'bar',
      data: chartData,
      options: myopt,
    };
    new Chart(canvas, options);
  }
```

the chart which this is generating is not equidistant  sharing image for reference
[image: Notice position and width of the bar]

position and width of the bar is incorrect and also I want to know if there is any way by which i can customize labels for y axis e.g. instead of **40,35,30...** it will be ** 40k,35k,30k** in y axis

If any one has worked on this case please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of the tick callback for your K at the end (https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/labelling.html#creating-custom-tick-formats)

```js
var ctx2 = document.getElementById("stack-chart");
var stackChart1 = new Chart(ctx2, {
  type: 'bar',
  options: {
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true,
          callback: (val) => (val + 'k')
        }
      }]
    },
    legend: {
      display: false,
      labels: {
        fontSize: 20,
        fontColor: '#595d6e',
      }
    },
    tooltips: {
      enabled: false
    }
  },
  data: {
    labels: ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'],
    datasets: [{
      backgroundColor: "#5e63b4",
      data: [20, 30, 40, 50, 60]
    }]
  },

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.4/Chart.min.js"></script>

<canvas id="stack-chart" width="1360" height="450"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thanks @LeeLenalee It solved my both problem. I just wonder what was wrong in my approach that forced bars not render as equidistant